# Missing file from computer "opencv_core249d.dll". Resolution with eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).Closed

Tags: opencv

I am facing  a problem with my visual studio 2013 ultimate. i would run a open cv project but iam getting a error message like this " opencv_core249d.lib" missing from ur computer. re install the program.
Solution : It works with eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

[image]

Comment: The error message says `opencv_core249d.dll`, not `opencv_core249d.lib`. Do you have the appropriate dll somewhere the OS can find it? That would be either in the working directory where you run your program or somewhere in the `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes its .dll not lib file. I have re configure all paths in visual studio and in the system. little improved but same error message displaying while executing. i manually updated v.2.4.9 .lib ->C:\opencv2.4.9\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib files in visual studio --> linker-->input--> additional dependencies.

If you could help to know exactly problem of below error statements. Thank you again.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1fvYZGFyvtYWRMV04wX1JJWFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Now its working with eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), Also configured minGW along with open cv. I received around 25 warnings  while building  but no errors. I wanted to detect only hand instead of all backgroud noise. any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a missing .dll issue, not a missing lib issue. It usually occurs when the Environment Variables have not been correctly set in your Windows environment. To take care of this problem, there are 2 methods:

1) edit Environment variables

- Go to ‘My Computer’ , right-click and select ‘Properties’. A window called ‘System’ will open, containing the Windows Logo on the right. On the left margin of this window, you will find a link named ‘Advance system
  settings’. Click on it.
- Another window called ’System Properties’ will open. On the bottom right corner of this window, click on the button named ’Environment Variables..’.
- Under the ‘System variables’ column, look for a variable by the name ‘Path’. - Select ‘Path’ and click ‘Edit..’
- In the ‘variable value’ row, **add** the following address:

  \path to\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin;

Please Note- Ensure that the new address added by you, and the address previously written in the ‘variable value’ row, are separated by a **;** **DO NOT REMOVE the previous environment variable addresses.**

2) Manually copy the .dll files.

In case the first approach does not work for you, go to:

```
\path to\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin;
```

You'll find all the dll files that you're looking for. Copy those files to directory where your source code is located.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes its .dll not lib file. I have re configure all paths in visual studio and in the system. little improved but same error message displaying while executing. i manually updated v.2.4.9 .lib ->C:\opencv2.4.9\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib files in visual studio --> linker-->input--> additional dependencies.

If you could help to know exactly problem of below error statements. Thank you again. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1fvYZGFyvtYWRMV04wX1JJWFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm afraid I've never come across these functions, but I think that your compiler is confusing cout with std::cout. Specifying namespaces should help

Comment: Now its working with eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), Also configured minGW along with open cv. I received around 25 warnings  while building  but no errors. I wanted to detect only hand instead of all backgroud noise. any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Great. You may edit the question and share your findings on it, and close it.